# Jquery submit form and send data without ajax

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I got well working form. Inside i have button that submit my form with onclick="form_submit()".
THIS CODE SAMPLE WORKS FINE BUT WITHOUT SENDING CONTROL-SUM.

```
function form_submit(){
    $("#add_form").submit();
}
```

Now i need to send some control-sum with post on submit form.
This control sum is inside other form input so it wont send with this one.

It is necessary to use non ajax solution. So i tried this way but without success.

```
function form_submit(){
   $("#add_form").submit(function() {
       $.post('url.php', $("#control-sum").serialize());
   })
}
```

Could you tell me please, what syntax or method use to find solution ?

Comment: Has the submit button a type="submit"? or is a type="button"?

Comment: Check if button type="submit" and preventDefault the inherit event of the form. `submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: You could always copy the control-sum from the other form, into your form as a hidden input, before you submit it

Comment: Submit button is like <button type="button" onclick="form_submit()">
Nice idea to copy input#control-sum with js.

Comment: have you tried using action tag in form

Comment: @R.Sarkar yes the form i working well and got all necessary tags. It just submit by the js function.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works fine and its solution that i need :)
Thanks for your help !

```
function form_submit(){
    var csum_val = $("#control-sum").val();
    var csum_name = $("#control-sum").attr('name');
    $(".jq__add_control_sum").append('<input type="hidden" name="' + csum_name + '" value="' + csum_val + '"/>');
    $("#add_form").submit();
}
```